# Is it possible to use extended precision (80-bit) floating point arithmetic in GHC/Haskell?

Tags: haskell, floating-point, ghc, floating-point-precision, extended-precision

The standard Haskell's [Double](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aDouble) uses [the standard double-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision):

> `data Double`
>   Double-precision floating point numbers. It is desirable that this type be at least equal in range and precision to the IEEE double-precision type.

Does GHC/Haskell offer somewhere also the [extended precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) (80-bit) floating point numbers, perhaps using some external library?

Comment: See: [GHC #3353: Add `CLDouble` support](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3353)

Comment: Also see [**this**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.0.0.0)

Answer (score 14):

As chuff has pointed out, you might want to take a look a the [numbers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers) package on hackage. You can install it with `cabal install numbers`. Here is an example:

```
import Data.Number.CReal -- from numbers

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn (showCReal 100 (sqrt 2))

-- output: 1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480731766797379907324784621070388503875343276415727
```

As the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/numbers/3000.1.0.3/doc/html/Data-Number-CReal.html) states, `showCReal` returns a string showing a given number of type `CReal` with the given number of decimals.

Comment: I guess I was assuming I was talking to a beginner... anyways. ;)

Comment: I don't think he's looking for arbitrary precision, just a way to take advantage of the 80-bit floating point capabilities of most popular processors.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the pointer to _numbers_, it might come in handy, but right now I'm looking just for the 80-bit floating point arithmetic.