# High precision floating point numbers in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, precision

I know Haskell has native data types which allow you to have really big integers so things like

```
>> let x = 131242358045284502395482305
>> x
131242358045284502395482305
```

work as expected. I was wondering if there was a similar "large precision float" native structure  I could be using, so things like

```
>> let x = 5.0000000000000000000000001
>> x
5.0000000000000000000000001
```

could be possible. If I enter this in Haskell, it truncates down to 5 if I go beyond 15 decimal places  (double precision).

Comment: Well, there's always `Rational` in `Data.Ratio` for abitrary precision fractions. But generally, the answer depends on what operations do you need it to support.

Comment: I suppose [`Rational`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Rational) is not ok for your purposes, i.e. you need the `Floating` instance?

Comment: For the highest possible precision: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Exact_real_arithmetic

(AERN implementation hasn't worked for a while though... I don't know if there are other candidates right now)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you are looking for:

- `Float` and `Double` - pretty much what you know and "love" from Floats and Doubles in all other languages.
- [`Rational`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Rational) which is a `Ratio` of `Integer`s
- [`FixedPoint`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/FixedPoint-simple) - This package provides arbitrary sized fixed point values.  For example, if you want a number that is represented by 64 integral bits and 64 fractional bits you can use `FixedPoint6464`.  If you want a number that is 1024 integral bits and 8 fractional bits then use `$(mkFixedPoint 1024 8)` to generate type `FixedPoint1024_8`.
- EDIT: And yes, I just learned about the `numbers` package mentioned above - very cool.

Comment: There's also [Data.Fixed](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Fixed.html) in `base`.

Comment: There's also a library for [cyclotomic numbers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cyclotomic) which are still exact, include all the rationals and more, and have more decidable predicates than the computable reals do.

Comment: I am wondering why the precision is not lazy in a lazy language like Haskell. I think it would be convenient, to get as much precision as needed for the result.

Comment: In a word, performance. Languages use doubles and machine words because that is what performs well. You can likely find lazy numbers implemented in Haskell but the performance will be much worse.

Answer (score 9):

Haskell does not have high-precision floating-point numbers naitively.

For a package/module/library for this purpose, I'd refer to [this answer to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797802/is-it-possible-to-use-extended-precision-80-bit-floating-point-arithmetic-in-g/16802696#16802696). There's also an example which shows how to use this package, called *[numbers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers)*.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this package exactly fits your demands though. Just check it out. ;)

Comment: Also have a look at the [hmpfr package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmpfr).

Answer (score 1):

If you need a high precision /fast/ floating point calculations, you may need to use FFI and long doubles, as the native Haskell type is not implemented yet (see https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3353).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the standard package for arbitrary precision floating point numbers is now https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific

Comment: It is certainly used quite widely, probably in part due to aeson's reliance on it. But it isn't really floating-point at all in the standard sense (being base-10), and as a consequence very badly suited for any actual computations. Sure it avoids the “problems” of representing long decimal numbers, but for many applications it just doesn't make sense to even consider decimal.