# Dividing by small quantities in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a question regarding numerical operations in Haskell.

I have a basic function:

```
derv::(Num a, Fractional a) => (a -> a) -> a -> a -> a
derv f a deltax = ((f (a+deltax))-(f a))/deltax
```

When I test it, this is the output I get:

```
    *Main> derv (\x->x*x) 2 0.000000000000000001
    0.0
    *Main> derv (\x->x*x) 2 0.00000000000001
    4.085620730620576
    *Main> derv (\x->x*x) 2 0.0000000001
    4.000000330961484
    *Main> derv (\x->x*x) 2 0.0001
    4.0001000000078335
    *Main>
```

When the divisor gets smaller, it makes the answer automatically go towards zero, rather than a more refined convergence toward 4. I'm curious as to why this is happening, especially given my type definition.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with haskell. Read [what every computer scientist should know about floating point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). (Note that you don't get 0 in the first test if you add `:: Rational`, because ghci uses exact rationals rather than floating point for the calculations then.) — BTW, using a fixed `δx` is a pretty horrible way of differentiating – very often, [automatic differentiation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad) is a much better choice.

Comment: `2 + epsilon == 2` in floating point arithmetic, for sufficiently small `epsilon`. Rounding does matter.

Comment: Side note: a central difference quotient `(f (a+deltax) - f (a-deltax)) / (2*deltax)` converges much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code the `0.000000000000000001` is probably being `defaulted` to `Double`, causing
a loss of precision after `2` is added because of rounding.

Using an exact representation such as `Rational` does not exhibit the same issue:

```
> import Data.Ratio
> derv (\x->x*x) 2 0.000000000000000001 :: Rational
4000000000000000001 % 1000000000000000000
> fromRational (derv (\x->x*x) 2 0.000000000000000001) :: Double
4.0
```

In the last line the loss of precision happens *after* the incremental ratio is computed, so the result is close to the exact fraction shown above.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to floating point rounding errors. You can use fixed point numbers, as is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878251/high-precision-floating-point-numbers-in-haskell).