# Haskell floating point operation precision

Tags: haskell

I have to make software to solve this problem:
http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=689

Basically, I need to calculate powers of rational numbers, for example 95.123^12 with arbitrary precision.

Is it possible to achieve it with haskell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [High precision floating point numbers in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878251/high-precision-floating-point-numbers-in-haskell)

Comment: Talking about floating point and "arbitrary precision" is just confusing people here—those are irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arbitrary precision rationals are possible to implement in every language (how easy it is depends, of course). In Haskell there is the [`Data.Ratio`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Ratio.html) module that gives you arbitrary precision rationals. Note that this isn't the same thing as floating point numbers.

Comment: I would change that to "exact rationals".

Comment: @dfeuer What would be the difference between an exact rational and a not-exact rational?

Comment: What is the "precision" of a rational? To a Scheme programmer, the notion of "inexact rational" would actually make perfect sense, and would mean a rational that was approximating something else; that concept does not really exist in Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

```
> import Data.Ratio
> 95.123^12 :: Rational
548815620517731830194541899025343415715973535967221869852721 % 1000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

That `%` is the fraction bar. You can also use it for input:

```
> (4%5)^12
16777216 % 244140625
```